# Image Type Validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. Working on an form validation having image in the form. Using Module MVC extension in CodeIgniter.

//for upooading image I found this file upload snippet

```
   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/audio_files/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
   $config['max_size']  = '2048';

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($file_name))
   {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $file1 = '';
   }
 else
   {
    $upload_data =  $this->upload->data();
    $file1 = $upload_data['file_name'];
   }
```

This is working fine. File which is not jpeg | gif is not uploaded. but user dont get any error message. I want the user to show that particular error when other image type is uploaded. Please help

I tried this but failed.

```
    try 1 : $this->template->load_partial('admin/admin_master', 'admin/form', $error); 
    try 2. : loading view with $error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you associate a view with an error message? For instance:

After

```
$file1 = '';
```

You put:

```
$this->load->view('error_view', $error, $file1);
```

You would have to make a separate view page called 'error_view.php'.

Comment: But that would be a differnnt view page. I want this to be part of my other form validation.

Comment: Not necessarily on the same page, but that's another story. What you're looking for is something called 'form validation callbacks': [link]http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks[/link]